# How can I use a wild card with .html in JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How can I use a wild card to update divs?

I want to change two sets of divs (one has additional information at the end).
I am using an each loop and do not want to do any sort of searching or find.  I know the beginning is the same for all the divs.

Want to change this one as well: `'#div\\\:'+month+'\\\:'+day+'\\\:'+time+'\\\:'+additionalInfo;`

First Div Type

```
div:2:25:1530
```

Second Div Type

```
 div:2:25:1530:3065
```

Code:

```
var div = '#div\\\:'+month+'\\\:'+day+'\\\:'+time;
$(div).html('<a class="btn btn-block btn-custom">TEST</a>');
```

I use the triple slash because the double was not working for some reason.  But worked when I added the third, not sure why.

Comment: There is no such thing as wild card in jQuery. But you can use generic enough selector and filter needed elements out.

Comment: please show sample of relevant html that you are trying to match selector to as well as your `each` loop. Your triple backslash escaping doesn't really make sense

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use one of the [attribute selectors](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/) to target multiple divs with a similar id or class name - there really isn't one for regexp

For example, say you have a div ID of `<div id="div:01:01:2015:info1"></div>`, you can target it with this selector:

Starts with selector `^=`

```
// target all divs for January (assuming mm:dd:yyyy)
$('[id^="div\\:01"]')
```

Contains selector `*=`

```
// target all divs for 2015
$('[id*="2015"]')
```

etc

---

Update: Use two backslashes `\\` to escape meta characters

```
 !"#$%&'()*+,./:;<=>?@[\]^`{|}~
```

Comment: Can I do this with a variable?  I build the div to look up in a each statement.  var div = '#div\\\:'+month+'\\\:'+day+'\\\:'+time;

Comment: I ended up doing $('[id^="div"]') and got what I needed.  Thanks!